# Making a priority queue gives error in java

Tags: java, priority-queue

I was trying a program in which I used a priority queue. When I make the Priority queue private, I get an error saying

```
KthSmallestPQ.java:8: error: illegal start of expression
            private PriorityQueue<MatrixElement> queue = new PriorityQueue<MatrixElement>(a[0].length, new Comparator<MatrixElement>() {
            ^
```

The code compiles and runs when I remove private. Can someone explain why making the PQ private gives an error?

Here's the code that works:

```
import java.util.*;

class KthSmallestPQ {
    public static int findKthLow(int[][] a, int k) {
        if(k < 0 || k >= a.length * a[0].length)
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        PriorityQueue<MatrixElement> queue = new PriorityQueue<MatrixElement>(a[0].length, new Comparator<MatrixElement>() { 
            public int compare(MatrixElement first, MatrixElement second) {
                return first.value - second.value;
            }
        });

        for(int i = 0; i < a[0].length; i++)
            queue.add(new MatrixElement(a[0][i], 0, i));

        MatrixElement lowest = null;

        for(int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            lowest = queue.remove();

        // add element from the next row of same column to the priority queue
            int row = lowest.row + 1;
            int col = lowest.col;

            if(row < a.length)
                queue.add(new MatrixElement(a[row][col], row, col));
            else
                queue.add(new MatrixElement(Integer.MAX_VALUE, row, col));
        }

    return lowest.value;
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix = {{10, 20, 30, 40},
                {15, 25, 35, 45},
                {24, 29, 37, 48},
                {32, 33, 39, 50}};

        int k = 6;
        System.out.println(k + "th smallest value is: " + findKthLow(matrix, k));
    }
}
class MatrixElement {
    int value;
    int row;
    int col;

    MatrixElement(int value, int row, int col) {
        this.value = value;
        this.col = col;
        this.row = row;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you make the right file(save it correctly). Because there is no `private` symbol in your source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `access specifier` on local variable.The variable `queue` you have created here is local variable.